# How to avoid Esri secure layer identity manager popup?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, authentication

I am new to Esri Identity manager, I am creating a secure layer service using identity manager, I have to avoid the secure layer login popup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a proxy page:
https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jshelp/ags_proxy.html
and embed the security token in there.
(or possibly even have it check one out for you with the proper credentials)